# Need help figuring out $\frac{d}{dx}(x^2)|{x=3}$

Tags: symbolic-computation

Okay, I punched this into my new calculator:

$$\frac{d}{dx}(x^2)|{x=3}$$

and it all is equal to $6$. What is this called and/or what does it do?

Comment: Evaluating a derivative of x^2 in respect to x at a fixed point (x = 3). Where did the sin term come from (another question)?

Comment: I got rid of it. I was just trying to figure out the math coding thing

Comment: Ok its called a derivative. Thank you Amzoti.

Comment: You shouldn't write a "thank you" as an answer. This site does not function as a forum where you can write posts. It is a question and answer format. Please see the FAQ.

Comment: Yeah and under etiquette it says to be nice. not vote people down for saying "thank you"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use simple derivative formula to solve this problem.

In this case use the formula:

$\frac{d}{dx}(x^2) = 2x$

Now put $x=3$

Answer will then come to $6$

For formulas, you may refer to: [**Basic Differentiation Formulas**](http://people.ucsc.edu/~miglior/diffform.pdf)